# How to make a canvas.circle disappear in android code?

Tags: android

I have been searching the web for days and i cant get anything.

I want to remove a circle when hit by the actor.

I have a clustered set of circles, and a circle that moves around randomly, so i want when a collision occurs a circle from the clustered set to be removed.

```
public void checkCollision() { 
   distance = (int) Math.sqrt(
                              (circlex-bal.x)*(circlex-bal.x)
                             +(circley-bal.y)*(circley-bal.y)
                    ); 
   if(distance <= radius+bal.ballRadius) { 
      //want to destroy the clustered set of ball 
   }
}
```

Comment: Give us some code. Show what you have already done.

Comment: thaks for reply. Here is what i have

Comment: public void checkCollision()
    {
    
     distance = (int) Math.sqrt((circlex-bal.x)*(circlex-bal.x)+(circley-bal.y)*(circley-bal.y));
     
     if(distance <= radius+bal.ballRadius)
     {
      //want to destroy the clustered set of ball
     }
     
    }

Comment: Haven't you got more, because there is no "Android code lines" here ? Please edit your post to add your code next time ! ;)